# How exactly did the knockout punch work in Ali vs Liston (1965)?

Tags: trivia, history, boxing

Ali vs Liston was a very famous match in the history of professional boxing, where Ali downed his opponent in a 1st round, 1st minute KO.

I was watching the [video of the match](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uzWynvBLJ4I), but wasn't really able to make out how the punch on the chin knocked out a professional boxer.

What exactly did the punch do?

How did it really knock out Sonny Liston?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the most controversial boxing matches in history.

Some argue that the Alì's punch has not knocked out his opponent, but currently there are no concrete information about it.

[On wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad_Ali_vs._Sonny_Liston) there is an dedicated page with many info and many hypothesis on this match (also on the possibility that was fixed).

**So, I think it is not possible to provide a concrete answer to these questions**

Comment: Yeah, even the reddit folks [suggested](https://www.reddit.com/r/Boxing/comments/4kzc5b/how_exactly_did_the_knockout_punch_work_in_ali_vs/d3j0ese) me to google "PhantomPunch".  But, google didn't give me convincing results.  Looks like it indeed is a controversy.  Anyways, I'll wait for about a week for any more helpful answers before accepting.  :)